# Sort an array composed by alphanumeric strings

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array in which the elements have like ID value "imm1", "imm2", "imm3"..."imm10"

the problem is that the sortOn method consider "imm10" lower than "imm2" because it consider 1 and 0 separatly. Then I tryed to write

```
immarray.sortOn("id", Array.NUMERIC)
```

but it don't apply the order correctly and I don't know why... maybe because my ID propriety have an alphanumeric value?
Then, how I can sort i t correctly?

I want this result:

```
imm1
imm2
imm3
...
imm10
imm11
imm12
etc...
```

Comment: are there any other prefixes other than "imm"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom sorting function. In that function you'll have to select the numeric values in the Strings and sort on them. In short:

```
immarray.sort(sortNumeric);

private function sortNumeric(a:String, b:String):int {
    return a.match(/\d+/g)[0] - b.match(/\d+/g)[0];
}
```

Some explanation: the regular expression `\d+` finds the numeric characters in the String. Note that this example is not programmed defensively and assumes that every String is formatted in the same way (e.g. 'imm10').